# Compute "percent complete" within subgroups using dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am running some analyses on concert setlists and song lyrics in R. I would like to compare certain song features across shows based on when they are played during a set. Currently, my data is in the following format, with show_num being the ID for the show and song_num being the song that was played 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on during that show.

```
track_name     show_num    song_num  lyrics
One Song       1           1         line 1
One Song       1           1         line 2
Another Song   1           2         line 1
Another Song   1           2         line 2
Final Song     1           3         line 1
Final Song     1           3         line 2
Final Song     1           3         line 3
One Song       2           1         line 1
```

I would like to create a new variable that computes how far along the show is when each song is played. For example, the previous dataset would ideally look something like this:

```
track_name     show_num    song_num  lyrics    perc_complete
One Song       1           1         line 1    .33
One Song       1           1         line 2    .33
Another Song   1           2         line 1    .67
Another Song   1           2         line 2    .67
Final Song     1           3         line 1    1.0
Final Song     1           3         line 2    1.0
Final Song     1           3         line 3    1.0
One Song       2           1         line 1    .20
One Song       2           1         line 1    .20
```

I tried to use a percentile rank approach

```
df = tour_w_lyrics%>%
  group_by(show_num) %>% 
  mutate(perc_complete=rank(song_num)/length(song_num))
```

but then quickly learned why there's no such thing as the 100th percentile. How might I create the ideal dataset using dplyr (preferably)? Or perhaps I am going about the analysis incorrectly? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can divide the current `song_num` with total number of songs in each show.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(show_num) %>% mutate(perc_complete = song_num/max(song_num))

# track_name  show_num song_num lyrics perc_complete
#  <fct>          <int>    <int> <fct>          <dbl>
#1 OneSong            1        1 line1          0.333
#2 OneSong            1        1 line2          0.333
#3 AnotherSong        1        2 line1          0.667
#4 AnotherSong        1        2 line2          0.667
#5 FinalSong          1        3 line1          1    
#6 FinalSong          1        3 line2          1    
#7 FinalSong          1        3 line3          1    
#.....
```

Or

```
df %>% group_by(show_num) %>% mutate(perc_complete = song_num/n_distinct(song_num))
```

---

In base R, we can use `ave` as

```
df$perc_complete <- with(df, song_num/ave(song_num, show_num, FUN = max))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(track_name = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("AnotherSong", "FinalSong", "OneSong"), class = "factor"), 
show_num = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), song_num = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), lyrics = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("line1", "line2", "line3"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Ah, I just realized *I* wrote my question wrong. I will try again, but what you suggested totally worked for my original post (in which the percentage increased by each row). Sorry for my inability to think.

Comment: @Hannah Okay, updated the answer based on your updated question.