# Using Dplyr to calculate percent by group for every column without specifying the name?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216530/r-can-dplyr-calculate-percents-by-group). However what I'm interested is to calculate the percentage for every column. So for example when I do the below I can calculate column S1 by explicity listing it, however I want a way to do it for all columns without specifying it.

```
input <- 'Gene  Exon    S1  S2  S3
G1  E1  56  52  95
G1  E2  25  52  5
G1  E3  32  66  22
G2  E1  55  11  33
G2  E2  46  12  44'

df = read.table ( text=input, header=T)
df$Exon = NULL 
df %>% group_by(Gene) %>% summarise ( per = S1 / sum (S1) )
```

Above will summarize the percent for S1 however when
I  tried using the a period it causes and error.

```
df %>% group_by(Gene) %>% summarise ( per = . / sum (.) )
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, when you paste strings with tabs into a SO question, the tabs are converted into spaces, so `sep="\t"` no longer works. I'm suggesting an edit to remove that so that your code will work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `across` for this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Gene) %>%
  summarize(across(matches("^S[0-9]+"), ~ . / sum(.)), .groups = "drop") 
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   Gene     S1    S2     S3
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 G1    0.496 0.306 0.779 
# 2 G1    0.221 0.306 0.0410
# 3 G1    0.283 0.388 0.180 
# 4 G2    0.545 0.478 0.429 
# 5 G2    0.455 0.522 0.571
```

Comment: thanks I also find that just doing by column number works as well, something like 1:3 instead of doing it by name S1:S3

Comment: Yes, that works too. It might be more robust to disregard column order, instead using `matches("^S[0-9]+")`. That way, you have much better control, and inadvertent column-reordering will not affect it. (I just edited the answer to reflect that, as I believe that resilience is important.)

Comment: cool - that is a neat trick and can be a really good way to disregard certain columns, eg non numeric ones are something you want to leave out for whatever reason.